# If statement in Calculator

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner programmer designing a calculator in Visual Studio 2013 using C#. I've run into a slight problem that I can't seem to fix. When I click on the square root button, I want the program to display the square root in the text box, as well as show what's happening in the label.

For example, if I want to calculate 9 + sqrt(16), I need to click 9 + 16, then press the square root button. The label above the text box should show "9 + sqrt(16)" and the text box itself should say "4". This all works like it should. But if I then take the square root of 4, I want the label to say "9 + sqrt(4)". I tried storing the first part (9 + ) as a string, but when the square root button is pressed twice, it displays "9 + sqrt(16) sqrt(4)".
Is there a different way to fix this or am I doing something wrong?

Here's part of the code I tried (result is the text box and expression is the label):

```
private void sqrt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
bool square_root_pressed = false;
string exp = "";
Button b = (Button)sender;
double res = Convert.ToDouble(result.Text);

if ((equal_pressed) || (operation == ""))
{
    if (b.Text == "√")
    {
        result.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Sqrt(res));
        expression.Text = "sqrt(" + Convert.ToString(res) + ") =";
    }
else
{
    result.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Sqrt(res));
    if (square_root_pressed)
    {
        expression.Text = exp + " sqrt(" + Convert.ToString(res) + ")";
    }
    else
    {
        exp = expression.Text;
        expression.Text = expression.Text + " sqrt(" + Convert.ToString(res) + ")";
        square_root_pressed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is far from a solution to your question but implementing a stack and utilising a Reverse Polish Notation algorithm will provide you with the means to keep track of the operations and values you have on hand which should also serve as the basis for tackling this problem, I believe.

Comment: Just curious are you trying to replicate the output from the windows calculator which would be 9 + sqrt(sqrt(16))

Comment: No I want to keep it a bit simpler and just show 9 + sqrt(4) so that it shows the most recent calculation.

Comment: just a note to help you also, `res.ToString()` extension method  will save you some typinging instead of using `Convert.ToString(res)`

Answer (score 0):

the local variable `square_root_pressed` is always set to false when the event handler is called. The statement

```
expression.Text = exp + " sqrt(" + Convert.ToString(res) + ")";
```

will never be reached.

Try to store the state of keys pressed outside of the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

you can add another event handler for "square root" and double the number when the Event is called,
once you click on the sqrt_Click Event "res" calculated the correct sqrt number.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question properly, when the square root button is pressed twice, the label display repeats `sqrt`. A possible solution is when the statement `exp = expression.Text` executes; check to see if the text `sqrt` already exists in the label. If so then remove it in-order to avoid duplication.

```
 exp = expression.Text;
 if (exp.Contains("sqrt"))
 { exp = exp.Remove(exp.IndexOf("sqrt")); }
 expression.Text = exp + " sqrt(" + Convert.ToString(res) + ")";
 square_root_pressed = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a totally different approach: I'd store the entire term as a list of objects and write a method to visualize them.

An example for what I mean could be the following:

```
public class Operation
{
    public string Operator;
}

public class Function
{
    public string Functor;
    public List<object> Term;
}
```

These two classes would be my little helpers. Now if the user presses only numbers and operators, you can fill a list of term items like this:

```
public List<object> term = new List<object>();

...

term.Add(3);
term.Add(new Operation() { Operator = "+" });
term.Add(4);
```

This would be the equivalent of `3+4`.

If the user presses the SQRT button, you could do this:

```
// Get the last element in the term and remove it
object o = term[term.Count - 1]; 
term.RemoveAt(term.Count - 1);

// Wrap the element in a function
Function f = new Function() { Functor = "SQRT" };
f.Term = new List<object>();
f.Term.Add(o);

// Add the function as new element to the term
term.Add(f);
```

This would turn the list from

```
3
+
4
```

into

```
3
+ 
SQRT
    4
```

Similarly, if the user presses SQRT again, you can remove the function:

```
// Get the last element in the term and remove it
object o = term[term.Count - 1]; 
term.RemoveAt(term.Count - 1);

// Add the function term as new element to the term
term.AddRange((o as Function).Term);
```